# Custom domain name setup in router for local access?

Tags: networking, router, dns, ping

Recently I purchased a TP Link router for my home use, and in the instructions they said you can access router cPanel from http://tplinkwifi.net/ domain.

But I am confused on how they have done that? When I pinged the domain from my home, it says it is pinging to 192.168.0.1 but when I did the same from my office, it says `ping: cannot resolve tplinkwifi.net: Unknown host`.

How they added a custom domain name which works only in the local router environment? Can I do the same?

Also are there any such router models which support local domain setup so that I can setup any domain name and point it to my local IP Address.

I know a way by modifying the hosts file in Windows but that is a lengthy process any way of doing the same via router or any CMS system?

Please advise?

Comment: What name server is configured on your local/home machine? If it is the router it's as easy as just having him resolve that name locally instead of asking a "internet" DNS server.

Comment: Linksys does the same... essentially, there's a custom route pre-programmed to send any requests to the address to `localhost` of the router, which is why it only works when you're connected to the LAN of the router.  While you could do a port redirect to access this from WAN, it is never advised to do so, as a router's WebUI _should never_ be accessible from WAN, unless its done so via SSH or a VPN tunnel _(VPN server on the router, not a 3rd party VPN)_

Answer (score 4):

**The router is intercepting and replying the DNS requests by itself.**

DNS is the system that resolves a domain name like `tplinkwifi.net` into an IP address like `192.168.0.1`. The protocol does not have any sort of encryption or security built in - your computer sends a DNS (plain-text) query to the DNS server, receives a (plain-text) response, and trusts it.

When using DHCP, your router can assign you which DNS' to use (a primary and a secondary one), but your computer can still override that.

In my case, my computer is connected to a TP-Link Archer C50 Router (`192.168.3.253`) over WiFi, getting its IP (`192.168.3.200`) via DHCP but with custom DNS servers set (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`). The `tplinkwifi.net` is resolving to `192.168.3.253` (which is not a standard IP for the router to be, so the resolution is not fixed), and even if I perform a DNS query explicitly targeted at the `8.8.8.8` DNS server, I get an immediate response with the local IP:

```
$ dig @8.8.8.8 tplinkwifi.net

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @8.8.8.8 tplinkwifi.net
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 48609
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;tplinkwifi.net.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
tplinkwifi.net.     1   IN  A   192.168.3.253

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Wed Jul 07 23:59:52 -03 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 48
```

So the conclusion is that the Router is intercepting the DNS query for that name, and responding it by itself, impersonating `8.8.8.8`. You can see the `1 msec` response time (I'm on a really bad internet connection, pinging `8.8.8.8` gives 30ms at best), so it has to be the router forging the response.

You can finally check on [Google Public DNS](https://dns.google.com/query?name=tplinkwifi.net) that the actual domain resolves to some other IP. To be able to visit that site, you should either connect to the Internet without going through a TP Link router that resolves this domain, hard-code those IPs on your local hosts file, or use DNS over HTTPs (DoH) to avoid the DNS query being intercepted by the router.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the model and administration interface you may or may not be able to add/modify DNS entries. What is happening is your computer receives the router as its primary DNS server through DHCP. The router either has a DNS server on it or has a hosts file that contains that address.

At no point will you be able to access that address outside of your local network because it is not a publicly registered domain.

If you want full control of DNS on your local network, you can setup bind9 on a raspberry pi and configure the router to point to it.